# Which among session, request and response objects, can we use without explicit declaration, in JSP?

Tags: jsp, el

I have come across this question in one of the JSP tutorials and tests.

Which among these three objects can we use in expressions and scriplets without having to declare them explicitely?

Answer (score 1):

We can use all of them in Jsp without declaring explicitly.

[Jsp Implicit objects](http://www.geekmantra.com/subsection.php?section=JSP&subSection=JSP%20Basics&permalink=41)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your time. Can you give me some reference link on it please?

Answer (score 1):

They're called *Implicit Objects* and they are all outlined in the [Java EE tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij). For future reference, here's an extract of relevance:

> ### [Implicit Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)
>
> The JSP expression language defines a set of implicit objects:
>
> - `pageContext`: The context for the JSP page. Provides access to various objects including:
>
>   - `servletContext`: The context for the JSP page’s servlet and any web components contained in the same application. See [Accessing the Web Context](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagl.html).
>   - `session`: The session object for the client. See [Maintaining Client State](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagm.html).
>   - `request`: The request triggering the execution of the JSP page. See [Getting Information from Requests](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html#bnafw).
>   - `response`: The response returned by the JSP page. See [Constructing Responses](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html#bnafz).
> - In addition, several implicit objects are available that allow easy access to the following objects:
>
>   - `param`: Maps a request parameter name to a single value
>   - `paramValues`: Maps a request parameter name to an array of values
>   - `header`: Maps a request header name to a single value
>   - `headerValues`: Maps a request header name to an array of values
>   - `cookie`: Maps a cookie name to a single cookie
>   - `initParam`: Maps a context initialization parameter name to a single value
> - Finally, there are objects that allow access to the various scoped variables described in [Using Scope Objects](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafo.html#bnafp).
>
>   - `pageScope`: Maps page-scoped variable names to their values
>   - `requestScope`: Maps request-scoped variable names to their values
>   - `sessionScope`: Maps session-scoped variable names to their values
>   - `applicationScope`: Maps application-scoped variable names to their values

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: +1 thanks for curating this list. It is exactly what I was after.